# Integrate npm into VisualStudio

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I got Linux. I have just installed Visual Studio and installed npm with it. However, when I type "npm init -y" into the Visual Studio console it says npm command not found. In the normal console I type npm version and it gives me back the version 3.5.2 though. So apparently I have not really integrated it into Visual Studio. Does anyone how to do so?

Comment: Well vscode is already using your computers shell so it should, did you close and open vscode and try it again?

Comment: Yes i did several times actually

Comment: inside your vscode terminal can you echo out your path and check if npm is there?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before... if you want to run npm commands you should go to a directory that your nodejs is installed... if you want to run npm commands in other directories you should go to the directory that you want and then run cmd and type in the commant

```
set path=C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

then you can run all of the npm commands in your directory